# Need Help building a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this, I have had a go at a number of things like using union queries but I think  I am looking in the wrong place.
I am trying to run a SQL query on a singular table to provide to users with only datareader permissions to discover total sales.

The table itself contains sales and refunds which have a type of 1 or 3 in the database.

Table example structure:

```
Reference    TransactionType  StockCode   Value
Sale01       1                Bat1         10
Sale01       1                Bat1         10
Sale09       1                Ball1         3
Sale15       1                Shin1        50
Sale16       1                Bat1         10
Refund06     3                Bat1         10
```

What I need to get is a total value for stock whereby the refund total is taken away from the total sum so that it appears as such:

```
StockCode         TotalSales
Bat1              20
Ball1              3
Shin1             50
```

This means that I would have to have a calcuation under one column that says:
Select (if type is 1 then sum(value) - (if type is 3 then sum(value)

In honestly I simply can't do it! I have tried using temporary tables and such but it has completely stumped me.

Comment: GROUP BY is what you want, and also use the aggregate function SUM.

Comment: no that didn't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
SELECT StockCode,   
    SUM( (CASE WHEN TransactionType = 3 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) * Value)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY StockCode
```

Comment: This is good but I do need to filter between type 1 and 3 as there are other types in the database

Comment: Just add a where clause  Where TransactionType in (1,3)